# jquery newbie: callback firing only once

Tags: jquery, callback

Newbie attempts a simple login form with jquery.

After clicking on the button, if there's a blank text field an error message should show, then hide.  It works once only, and if the button is clicked a second time, the callback isn't fired.

Any help much appreciated!

```
$("#login_button").click(function(event){
        if ($('#email').val() == "" || $('#password').val() == "") {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#err_msg")   .addClass("ui-state-error ui-corner-all")
                    .text("Insert your email address and password")
                    .show("Blind", 500, callback);
        }

        function callback() {
            setTimeout(function(){
                $("#err_msg").removeAttr("style").fadeOut();
            }, 1000);
        };
    });


    <div id="err_container">
        <div id="err_msg" ><%= errReason %></div>
    </div>
    <form id="login_form" name="login_form" method="post" 
        action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/loginhandler">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>&nbsp;USER LOGIN&nbsp;</legend>
    <div>
        <label for="email">Email: </label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="password">Password: </label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <button id="login_button" 
            class="ui-button ui-button-text-only ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" type="submit">&nbsp;Login&nbsp;
        </button>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in you call to .Show(),
it should be:

```
$("#err_msg").addClass("ui-state-error ui-corner-all").text("Insert your email address and password").show(500, callback);
```

See this working jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/UxUap/

Comment: Many Thanks for pointing that out! I had an uppercase "B" for the "blind" effect.  Stupid me.